# problem with trying to return an API not sure whats missing from my code but the console sells error in javascript line 15

Tags: javascript, json, api

[image: javascript image]

The console tells me that in line 15 of my javascript there is an error but i am unsure of what it is. My button i created in html does not return my api facts and I am using a cord extension as well.

Comment: Your actual code should be posted here, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate each object property with a comma.